# Moving a subtree of a BST up

Tags: arrays, recursion, binary-search-tree

i'm currently working on a function that moves a subtree of a BST one level up. the BST is saved in an array with the root of the tree being at index 0, the left child of i at 2i +1 and the right child at 2i + 2 and so one.
My current approach in pseudocode is:

```
shiftUp(int from, int to) {
    if (!existsNode(from))
        return
    tree[to] = tree[from]
    tree[from] = NIL
    shiftUp(leftChild(from), leftChild(to))
    shiftUp(rightChild(from), rightChild(to))
}
```

But this doesn't work correctly, e.g. if I have a BST like this (Node **a** at position 0 and Node **b** at position 1) and call shiftUp(1, 0) to move the subtree with root **b** to where node **a** is, then node **f** is moved to where node **d** is and node **d** is overwritten and lost.

```
       a
      /
     b  
   /  \
  c    d
 / \
e   f
```

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: You are shifting up the children of f not f.  Since d has not children you want to put f as left child of d.  If d already has a left child then add f to d right child.

Comment: Could you specify the expected result of this operation? For example, what happens if we apply the same shift up operation to the tree from your example with additional 3 nodes all going down from `a` to the right as in https://pastebin.com/6vgPF6XQ i.e filling additionally `tree[2] = x`, `tree[6] = y` and `tree[14] = z`. What happens to the nodes in that branch? Are all of them lost? Or is only the first (driect) child `x` overridden by `d` and the rest 2 nodes (`y` and `z`) stay in place? Or does something else happen?